# Can I reopen/extend the bounty on a question?

Tags: support, bounty, timestamps

10 days ago I asked a question here:

[What is the difference between a Spine, Register, and Index?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/311668/what-is-the-difference-between-a-spine-register-and-index)

On the following day (Sunday) I added a bounty worth 50 reputation.

That expired this Sunday gone, while an answer was posted on Friday.

At the time of the answer being posted, and when the bounty ended, I was unfortunately unable to review the question.

As such, when I saw the answer yesterday (and asked for some minor follow up info which was provided), it was too late to award the bounty.

This answer (even before I asked for the minor additions) IMO answered my question very well.

Is it possible to extend the bounty so the user who posted the answer can be justly rewarded?

Comment: can start a second bounty (e.g. "reward an existing answer") but it will have to be double the first one (however, you don't currently have the reputation to start any bounties at all)

Comment: @Glen_b Thanks for the info - yeah, I tried to find it again and came across the doubling :/ It's just unfortunate, as the answer was good and I wanted to respect that.

Comment: It's not an insurmountable problem.

Comment: True. A useful perspective that is.

Comment: Thanks @Glen_b for funding a new bounty out of your own pocket - whether it ends up going to me or to someone else, it definitely benefits the community by encouraging people to answer questions.

Comment: @Glen_b I echo the sentiments of Candamir. Thank you for adding it on.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unfortunately, the [answer is **no**](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/bounty). You must assign the bounty during the bounty + grace period; otherwise it vanishes. If you don't award a bounty and there is an answer with the highest score (minimum 2 upvotes) gets half of the bounty. Bounties cannot be canceled, prolonged, etc.